# Shapes not alligned for exaclty same shapes in statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I'm using `pandas` dataframes and series as test and train data. I'm checking shapes of my train dataframe and test dataframe and they are absolutely identical. But I still have `shapes not aligned` error. Here is my fit/predict code:

```
train_df = df.loc[:50]
X_train = train_df[["Value", "Momentum", "Quality", "MinimumVolatility"]]
y_train = train_df["P1ExRe"]

X_train = sm.add_constant(X_train)

model = sm.OLS(y_train, X_train)
results = model.fit()
test_df = df.loc[51:100]
x_test = test_df[["Value", "Momentum", "Quality", "MinimumVolatility"]]
y_test = test_df["P1ExRe"]

print(x_test.shape==X_train.shape)
model.predict(x_test)
```

Here is the error:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-832ad1f6bc61> in <module>
      4 
      5 print(x_test.shape==X_train.shape)
----> 6 model.predict(x_test)

~/projects/courserads/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py in predict(self, params, exog)
    378             exog = self.exog
    379 
--> 380         return np.dot(exog, params)
    381 
    382     def get_distribution(self, params, scale, exog=None, dist_class=None):

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (50,5) and (50,5) not aligned: 5 (dim 1) != 50 (dim 0)
```

Comment: The error message looks strange. It would mean that `params` is 2-dimensional with shape (50, 4).  Does `summary()` look reasonable? What's the shape of `y_train`, is it a pandas Series?

Comment: Did you run `sm.OLS(y_train, X)` instead of `sm.OLS(y_train, X_train)`

Comment: @Josef I'm not a big expert but `summary` looks reasonable for me. The shape of `params` is (5,), the shape of `y_train` is (50,)

Comment: @StupidWolf actually I did. Sorry that was a typo. I edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `model.predict` method. You should use `results.predict(...)`.

Model predict requires `params`, because only the results has the estimated parameters.

Your `x_test` in model.predict is interpreted as `params` and causes the shape mismatch.